# How can I see the number of rollbacks in my STM in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, stm

How can I see the number of rollbacks in my STM in Clojure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't... unless you are willing to cheat:

```
(defmacro spy-dosync [& body]
  `(let [retries# (atom -1)
         result# (dosync
                   (swap! retries# inc)
                   ~@body)]
     (println "retries count:" @retries#)
     result#))
```

and then replace your dosync by a spy-dosync.

Answer (score 5):

If you're feeling frisky, you could hack the Clojure source and rebuild (it's [easy](http://clojure.org/patches) to rebuild the Clojure source).  Transaction retries happen in src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java in the run() method.  There's a big for loop there that goes until done or RETRY_LIMIT.  The value of i when the loop exits should be the retry count.

Answer (score 2):

There is STM-stress [test](https://gist.github.com/456326) written by Chris Houser which could be useful