# Counting aborted transactions in Clojure

Tags: transactions, clojure, functional-programming

I would like to analyze the behavior of a Clojure program versus a locking version in C. One metric I would like to track is the total number of aborted transactions for my Clojure program.

The only problem is that I can't mutate a variable outside of the context of the transaction that I am in. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
(dosync
(try
  (alter my_num inc)
  (catch Throwable t
    (do
      (alter total_aborts inc)
      (println "Caught " (.getClass t))
      (throw t)))))
```

Of course, total_aborts will never get incremented if the transaction doesn't finish!!! So how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792197/how-can-i-see-the-number-of-rollbacks-in-my-stm-in-clojure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `my-num` and `total-aborts` [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) and use `swap!` instead of `alter`.

Comment: Thanks!I had forgotten about atoms.